# Mutable Array in GHC Compact Region

Tags: haskell, ghc

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to put a `MutableArray#` in
a compact region. Doing this is explicitly discouraged by [ghc devs](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/13508)
and by [the documentation](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/master/libraries/html/compact/Data-Compact.html)
because it allows users to point to something outside of the `Compact`.
That aside, I'm still interested in trying to do this, with the understanding
that I would be responsible for ensuring that the array only point to things
inside the same `Compact`.

My line of thinking was to add an `Array#` to a compact region and then
attempt to thaw it using `unsafeThawArray#`:

```
unsafeThawArray# :: Array# a -> State# s -> (#State# s, MutableArray# s a#)
```

I should then be able to use `writeArray#`, provided that (a) everything I
write into the `MutableArray#` is in the same compact region and (b) I
evaluate everything to WHNF with `seq` before writing it to the array. I think this would be safe. I do have one concern based on the 
[stg_unsafeThawArrayzh commentary](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/browser/ghc/rts/PrimOps.cmm#L261):

> A MUT_ARR_PTRS lives on the mutable list, but a MUT_ARR_PTRS_FROZEN normally doesn't...

I don't understand the internals of GHC well, but here is my understanding of the comment:
There is something called the mutable list, which has a bunch of mutable arrays and
is occassionally scan by the GC. For my purposes, this is problematic, since it means
that `unsafeThawArray#` will cause the GC to start scanning things in a compact region.
That's not good. But, maybe my understanding is wrong, which would be great.

If `unsafeThawArray#` cannot do what I need, I was thinking that `unsafeCoerce#` would
do it, but I again I'd like to hear from someone knowledgeable on this subject. Thanks and let me know if I can clarify anything.

EDIT: Just a comment for future readers. After thinking about this more, I realized that using `SmallArray#` instead of `Array#` would be better. It should make writes faster. Compare the code for [writing to MutableArray#](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/browser/ghc/compiler/codeGen/StgCmmPrim.hs#L1381) with the code for [writing to SmallMutableArray#](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/browser/ghc/compiler/codeGen/StgCmmPrim.hs#L2089). The card table that `MutableArray#` keeps updated is worthless when everything is on the compact heap since it's never going to get scanned anyway.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is an interesting idea and while it's a all quite subtle, I believe you can get away with it.

As you point out, the garbage collector needs to track which arrays are mutable as they may contain references to objects residing in younger generations than that of the array itself. Objects on this list will serve as roots when collecting younger generations.

To see why, imagine that you allocate (in the nursery, generation 0) a mutable array with some pointers to other newly-allocated heap objects. On garbage collection, both the array and its contents will be moved to generation 1, meaning that it won't need to be traversed when we scavenge for generation 0.

Now imagine that we allocate a new heap object in generation 0 and mutate an array element to reference it. Now consider what happens when we garbage collect the nursery: if we look only at references within generation 0, we will mistakenly conclude that our newly allocated object is dead. This is obviously wrong: our new object is live via its reference from the array in generation 1.

For this reason, we must maintain a mutable object list for each generation, which we will scavenge as roots when we collect younger generations.

However, as your intuition suggested, this should be unnecessary in a compact region as we shouldn't be scavenging the region's contents anyways. Moreover, since the heap representation of `MutableArray#` and `Array#` are identical (other than the info table pointer), your use of `unsafeCoerce#` should be fine.

All of this is naturally contingent on carefully preserving the closure invariant that compact regions obey. This requires that all computation eventually reduce to some sort of lookup in the region. Strictly speaking even this isn't quite enough as Haskell's semantics don't guarantee that a copy won't be produced, but in the case of GHC Haskell this shouldn't be a problem.

## An Example

Here's a small playground that I used to test this.

```
{-# LANGUAGE MagicHash #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UnboxedTuples #-}
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}

import GHC.IO
import GHC.Compact
import GHC.Exts hiding (toList)

data Wombat = Wombat String deriving Show

n = 10000

wombats :: [Wombat]
wombats = take n $ cycle $ map Wombat [ "harry", "jerry", "carry", "larry", "fred" ]

main :: IO ()
main = do
    c <- fromListM (length wombats) wombats >>= compact
    let arr = getCompact c
    flip mapM_ [1..n-1] $ \i -> do
        swapMutArray i ((i+2) `mod` n) arr
    mapM_ print (toList arr)
    return ()

(!) :: MutArray a -> Int -> a
(!) (MutArray a) (I# n) =
    case indexArray# a n of
      (# x #) -> x

data MutArray a = MutArray (Array# a)

getMutArray :: MutArray a -> MutableArray# s a
getMutArray (MutArray arr) = unsafeCoerce# arr

fromListM :: Int -> [a] -> IO (MutArray a)
fromListM = \n@(I# n#) xs ->
    IO $ \s0 -> case newArray# n# x0 s0 of
                  (# s1, arr #) -> unIO (go arr (n-1) xs) s1
  where
    x0 = error "hi"
    go arr (-1) [] = IO $ \s0 -> case unsafeFreezeArray# arr s0 of
                                   (# s1, arr' #) -> (# s1, MutArray arr' #)
    go arr n@(I# n#) (x:xs) = do
        IO $ \s0 -> case writeArray# arr n# x s0 of s1 -> (# s1, () #)
        go arr (n-1) xs
    go _ _ _ = error "uh oh"

toList :: Show a => MutArray a -> [a]
toList arr@(MutArray arr#) = go 0
  where
    !len = I# (sizeofArray# arr#)
    go n
      | n == len = []
      | otherwise = (arr ! n) : go (n + 1)

writeMutArray :: Int -> a -> MutArray a -> IO ()
writeMutArray (I# i) x arr =
    IO $ \s0 -> case writeArray# (getMutArray arr) i x s0 of s1 -> (# s1, () #)

swapMutArray :: Int -> Int -> MutArray a -> IO ()
swapMutArray m@(I# m#) n@(I# n#) arr = do
    !x <- IO $ readArray# (getMutArray arr) m#
    !y <- IO $ readArray# (getMutArray arr) n#
    writeMutArray n x arr
    writeMutArray m y arr
```

Comment: Could you explain what sorts of measures must be taken to ensure that the array doesn't accidentally point to any thunks outside the region? Speaking of which, I'm wondering if GHC Core should recognize a primitive array type that can only contain forced values (as though each element were marked with a `!`). The runtime representation would be the same, but there'd be no risk of double forcing.

Comment: I've added notes on the matter near the end.

Comment: It would be nice if there was a good way to validate that nothing had actually gone awry. Even if `swapArray` had been misdefined (eg, by being insufficiently strict with the result of `readArray#`), this example would probably still work. We wouldn't see any problems until a GC ran and then something in the compact was pointing to a garbage address. Even then, it might take several GCs before a segfault happens. It seems like it would be nice to have a primop that could check that a compact was still valid. Granted, for people not trying to do weird stuff, this primop would be worthless.

Comment: Indeed it would be nice if there were a better way to test things like this; locally I tested this with much higher values of `n` than I cited here to ensure that there was plenty of opportunities for the garbage collector to run wild. That being said, this method is obviously far from perfect.

Comment: I should mention that the debug RTS also supports a number of sanity checks (enabled with the `+RTS -D` flags) which can catch some classes of issues. I don't know off hand what bugs, if any, they would catch in the above example, however.

Comment: @bgamari Thanks. I'll look into the sanity checks. Also, I realized that there's something in your answer that doesn't totally click in my mind. When someone calls `unsafeFreezeArray#`, it seems like they would end up with an immutable value that can point to younger generations. It [doesn't seem like](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/browser/ghc/compiler/codeGen/StgCmmPrim.hs#L384) GHC changes the frozen array to be in generation 0, so I don't understand how this works with garbage collection.

Comment: nevermind, just found out about [eager promotion](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Rts/Storage/GC/EagerPromotion), which answers my question.